# Avoiding repeating words in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

Could a native speaker please help me with writing the below sentence in a better way?

> Please do not feel guilty anymore, this makes me upset and makes me think I've
>   done things wrongly.

The point that I am not sure about is whether I can omit one of the "makes me"s or not. If I do so, I get

> Please do not feel guilty anymore, this makes me upset and think I've
>   done things wrongly.

It looks better than the first sentence, but I am not sure f it is clear or not. Also, in the above sentence, I want the word "this" to refer to "you feeling guilty", but I am not sure if it is clear from the sentence or not.

Comment: You can accomplish this if you replace *think* with a different verb, and use the opposite of the final word: *Please do not feel guilty anymore, this makes me upset and **doubt if** I've done things **correctly**.*

Comment: No; omitting the second 'makes me' leaves an awkward zeugma. Admittedly not as bad as 'John made her a good husband and a cup of tea.'  Deletions must be handled with care. 'Please do not feel guilty anymore – this  upsets me and makes me think I've handled things badly.'

Comment: “Done things wrong” is what  most native speakers would write. “Wrong” has become an adverb, and “wrongly” sounds awkward to me. But I think that if your question is about basic usage by native speakers you should be asking it on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite right to sense that this first sentence is not a good one, even though it is grammatically correct.  The problem is one of style rather than of usage.  Repetition of a key word, unless you do it for rhetorical purposes, is clumsy. But there is an obvious way round the difficulty.

There is a perfectly good transitive verb, *to upset*.  So use it.

> Please do not feel guilty any more. This upsets me and makes me and makes me feel I have done things wrongly.

There is something else that you did not ask about. I suggest you should have put your explanation the other way round:

> This makes me feel I have done things wrongly and upsets me.

Being upset is the effect of feeling you have done things wrongly, and is not an independent second reason.

Answer (score 0):

Coordination can be used in cases where the sense of the head element - the verb *make* in this case - is the same for both elements in the coordination (CaGEL p1327). In this case however, there are two different senses of *make* involved:

makes me upset

> 5.a.To cause to be or become: *made her position clear; a decision that
>   made him happy.*

makes me think...

> 6.b.To compel: *made him quit*.

([American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=make))

These two - *upset* and *think I've...* - are not good candidates for a coordination.

As far as *this* with antecedent *feel guilty anymore*, there would have to be more context in order to tell whether there would be confusion or not. A simple *it* in place of *this* might avoid confusion in some cases.

To avoid repetition, you might choose another word for one of the instances of *make*.

e.g.

> Please do not feel guilty anymore, it only makes me upset and causes
>   me to think I've done things wrongly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the word "it" better than the word "this" in the sentence?

Comment: It sounds more natural to my ears, but there's no clear reason for picking one over the other. Another possibility would be _that_.

Comment: Or you could use "it only upsets me and..."

Comment: Happy with the comma splice?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down the original sentence, you see a lot of words that are needed in more formal languages, but not commonly used in English:

> Please do not feel guilty *anymore*.

The "anymore" is unnecessary. "Please do not feel guilty" is punchy and direct, and doesn't come off as rude in English. I don't know what your native tongue is, however, a lot of languages see that sort of directness as intrinsically rude, while English does not.

> this makes me upset

"This upsets me." Upset can stand on its own, so "makes" is unnecessary here.

> and makes me think I've done things wrongly.

You could simplify to "and makes me think I've done wrong" though, "done wrong" is a bit of a regionalism in the States. "and makes me think I've done *something* wrong" would be a more general case. "Things" should always make you suspicious; "something" is an acceptable indeterminate use, while "things" sounds odd and slapdash. "Wrongly" is very uncommon.

That leaves us with:

> "Please do not feel guilty. This upsets me, and makes me think I've done something wrong."

That's pretty solid, and contains the core of your original statements. However, if I was going to say it myself, I think the most effective way to do it is to shorten it further, and just make two simple, direct, sentences.

> Please don't feel guilty. It makes me feel like I've done something
>   wrong.